# CSS File with Query String Returned as Text/Plain on Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, mime

I have a problem where Apache 2.4 is returning all css files as mime type `text/plain` but only if I have a query string at the end EG:

```
homepage.css - works
homepage.css?seed=123323980 does not
```

This was fine on Apache 2.2, but on Apache 2.4 I can't get it to work.

Comment: Must be something like your own rewrites somehow, doesn't happen for me.

Comment: I have the same issue and in deed I'm using mod rewrite to deliver cached dynamic generated content

Comment: In the end my problem had nothing to do with mod_rewrite, upgrading to apache 2.4 it was suggested to replace DefaultType with ForceType.  here I found a solution http://www.spinics.net/lists/apache-users/msg110288.html